# How is SplSubject/SplObserver useful?

Tags: php, observer-pattern, spl

The [Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) includes what some resources call a reference implementation of the Observer pattern, by way of the [`SplSubject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splsubject.php) and [`SplObserver`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php) classes.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how these are very useful with no way to pass actual events or any other information along with the notifications:

```
class MySubject implements SplSubject {
    protected $_observers = [];

    public function attach(SplObserver $observer) {
        $id = spl_object_hash($observer);
        $this->_observers[$id] = $observer;
    }

    public function detach(SplObserver $observer) {
        $id = spl_object_hash($observer);

        if (isset($this->_observers[$id])) {
            unset($this->_observers[$id]);
        }
    }

    public function notify() {
        foreach ($this->_observers as $observer) {
            $observer->update($this);
        }
    }
}

class MyObserver implements SplObserver {
    public function update(SplSubject $subject) {
        // something happened with $subject, but what
        // was it???
    }
}

$subject = new MySubject();
$observer = new MyObserver();

$subject->attach($observer);
$subject->notify();
```

It seems like these interfaces are pretty much useless for any real world problem.  Can someone enlighten me?

---

**Edit:**

Here's my biggest problem with the interface (although there are others):

```
public function update(SplSubject $subject, Event $event) { /* ... */ }
```

...nets the following fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of MyObserver::update() must be compatible with SplObserver::update(SplSubject $SplSubject)
```

**Edit #2:**

Making the additional parameters optional by giving them defaults prevents the fatal error and provides a way to pass context, making implementations worthwhile.  I wasn't previously aware of this, so this pretty much answers my question.  The solution is to pass your own event/message data, and check for its existance inside `SplObserver::update()`.

Comment: I've always felt this textbook implementation was lame. The observer must poll the subject for the changed data, yet it needs to freakin use `instanceof` before it can safely do so. However, note that the following satisfies the method signature `update(SplSubject $subject, $event = null)` and helps the situation a whole lot.

Comment: @rambocoder: Yes, it prevents the fatal error, but opens up the code to run-time errors unless you specifically check `isset($event)` (which isn't a huge problem, but as simple as the Observer pattern is, I could rewrite these interfaces in a couple minutes and avoid all these issues).

Comment: Well, you need to check for null regardless. The bigger taboo is you need to use instanceof because typehinting splsubject doesn't guarantee you any object specific methods.

Comment: @rambocoder: If the interface allowed me to do `public function update(SplSubject $subject, Event $event)` (no default), then checking for null would not be necessary, but that's obviously not possible due to the signature mismatch.  Giving the added param a default solves this, though, which was my original issue.  If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ah you're right. I forgot php throws when you pass a null(too much java for me lately).

Comment: @drrcknlsn, consider a self-answer for the bounty as well.  Now that we know how to actually provide *context* for events, things just got much more interesting.  That was also my primary complaint about the SPL interfaces.  I'm still looking for a great, practical **real-world** example.  Everything given so far is just throwaway demo code, outside of the one link to the Zend DevZone, and I'm not sure if that counts.

Comment: @Charles I had a quick glance at [the source for `SplObserver` and `SplSubject` (PHP 5.4)](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/spl/spl_observer.c) hoping that they were implemented by some other SPL class - It looks like the original intention was to use them with `SplObjectStorage`, which has both attach and detach methods, but no notify. However both of these interfaces are unused and contain zero functionality. While they might help implement the pattern by hinting the methods that could be used, they serve little to no purpose otherwise.

Comment: You can assign values to undefined properties in php. Why not just set `$this->event_name` in notify method before calling `update`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement the update method with an optional parameter and still satisfy the SplSubject interface.

```
class MyObserver implements SplObserver {
    public function update(SplSubject $subject, $eventData = null) {
        if (is_null($eventData))
            // carefull
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38):

`It seems like these interfaces are pretty much useless for any real world problem. Can someone enlighten me?`

**Interface**

While abstract classes let you provide some measure of implementation, interfaces are pure templates. An `interface` can only `define functionality`; it can never implement it. An interface is declared with the interface keyword. It can contain properties and method declarations, but not method bodies.

**Interface Use case**

For example if you want to your project should support different databases . so that you can change your database in future its better to use interfaces that contains property procedures in class file with out altering objects

`By itself, interfaces are not very useful` because You cannot create instances of interfaces but  Interfaces are instrumental in enforcing object oriented design methodologies `which in real sense makes your live easier as a programmer` because the   foremost incentive for object oriented programming is encapsulation *(You don't care how a capability is implemented. You, as a programmer, are exposed only to the interface. This is also a good way to watch after the system architecture)*

**SplSubject & SplObserver**

Orthogonality is a virtue , One of objectives as programmers should be to build components that can be altered or moved with minimal impact on other components.

If every change you make to one component necessitates a ripple of changes elsewhere in the codebase, the task of development can quickly become a spiral of bug creation and elimination.

There is no special feature of [SplSubject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splsubject.php) and [SplObserver](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php) because thy are both `interface to implement the Observer Design Pattern.`

[Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems

- The Observer pattern defines an one-to-many dependency between a subject object and any number of observer objects so that when the subject object changes state, all its observer objects are notified and updated automatically.
- The Observer pattern essentially allows an unlimited number of objects to observe or listen to events in the observed object (or subject) by registering themselves. After observers are registered to an event, the subject will notify them when the event is fired.
- The subject handles this by storing an observer collection and iterating through it when the event occurs in order to notify each observer.
- Observer Pattern registers observers with a subject.
- You might have multiple observers. Subject must keep a list of registered observers and when event occurs it fires (provides notification) all registered observers.
- Unregister also possible when we do not need any observer.

**Example 1. Interest Rate Notification System for a Loan**

```
$loan = new Loan("Mortage", "Citi Bank", 20.5);
$loan->attach(new Online());
$loan->attach(new SMS());
$loan->attach(new Email());

echo "<pre>";
$loan->setIntrest(17.5);
```

Output

```
Online    : Post online about modified Intrest rate of : 17.50
Send SMS  : Send SMS to premium subscribers : 17.50
Send Email: Notify mailing list : 17.50
```

**Example 2. Simple User Register Monitor**

```
$users = new Users();

new Audit($users);
new Logger($users);
new Security($users);

$users->addUser("John");
$users->addUser("Smith");
$users->addUser("Admin");
```

Output

```
Audit    : Notify Audit about John
Log      : User John Create at Wed, 12 Dec 12 12:36:46 +0100
Audit    : Notify Audit about Smith
Log      : User Smith Create at Wed, 12 Dec 12 12:36:46 +0100
Audit    : Notify Audit about Admin
Log      : User Admin Create at Wed, 12 Dec 12 12:36:46 +0100
Security : Alert trying to create Admin
```

**Advantage of Observer Design Pattern:** 
Main advantage is loose coupling between objects called observer and observable. The subject only know the list of observers it don’t care about how they have their implementation.All the observers are notified by subject in a single event call as Broadcast communication

**Disadvantage of Observer Design Pattern:**

- The disadvantage is that the sometime if any problem comes, debugging becomes very difficult because flow of control is implicitly between observers and observable we can predict that now observer is going to fire and if there is chain between observers then debugging become more complex.
- Another issue is Memory management when dealing with large observers

**Common Classes**

```
abstract class Observable implements SplSubject {
    protected $_observers = [];

    public function attach(SplObserver $observer) {
        $id = spl_object_hash($observer);
        $this->_observers[$id] = $observer;
    }

    public function detach(SplObserver $observer) {
        $id = spl_object_hash($observer);

        if (isset($this->_observers[$id])) {
            unset($this->_observers[$id]);
        }
    }

    public function notify() {
        foreach ( $this->_observers as $observer ) {
            $observer->update($this);
        }
    }
}



abstract class Observer implements SplObserver {
    private $observer;

    function __construct(SplSubject $observer) {
        $this->observer = $observer;
        $this->observer->attach($this);
    }
}
```

**Load Example Classes**

```
class Loan extends Observable {
    private $bank;
    private $intrest;
    private $name;

    function __construct($name, $bank, $intrest) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->bank = $bank;
        $this->intrest = $intrest;
    }

    function setIntrest($intrest) {
        $this->intrest = $intrest;
        $this->notify();
    }

    function getIntrest() {
        return $this->intrest;
    }
}

class Online implements SplObserver {

    public function update(SplSubject $loan) {
        printf("Online    : Post online about modified Intrest rate of : %0.2f\n",$loan->getIntrest());
    }
}

class SMS implements SplObserver {

    public function update(SplSubject $loan) {
        printf("Send SMS  : Send SMS to premium subscribers : %0.2f\n",$loan->getIntrest());
    }
}

class Email implements SplObserver {

    public function update(SplSubject $loan) {
        printf("Send Email: Notify mailing list : %0.2f\n",$loan->getIntrest());
    }
}
```

**User Register Example Classes**

```
class Users extends Observable {
    private $name;

    function addUser($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->notify();
    }

    function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
class Audit extends Observer {

    public function update(SplSubject $subject) {
        printf("Audit    : Notify Autify about %s\n", $subject->getName());
    }
}
class Logger extends Observer {

    public function update(SplSubject $subject) {
        printf("Log      : User %s Create at %s\n", $subject->getName(),date(DATE_RFC822));
    }
}
class Security extends Observer {
    public function update(SplSubject $subject) {
        if($subject->getName() == "Admin")
        {
            printf("Security : Alert trying to create Admin\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `Observable` might actually be useful as a Trait.  (My wording is very non-committal: I tend to treat traits like they don't exist)

Comment: I don't really think so  ...  best answer on Traits Vs. Interface have seen ... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205347/1226894

Comment: This answer fails to address the question, but highlights the problem.  The update methods only know that $subject implements SplSubject, and yet they call $subject->getName() which is not defined by the interface.  SplSubject does not define a way to get information from the subject, so it can't safely know what methods it can call on the subject, unless it checks the instance type, which mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Baba - +1 and thanks for the answer, but one more comment here will be added here, you **can** create instances of interfaces but **not** in PHP, however if you checked if an object is **instanceof** interface, it will return **true** if the object's class implements this interface.

Comment: The observer pattern is massively useful, especially in more complicated systems. You can keep an eye on the various states of your system in any number of ways you can imagine (log things, email, sms, slack notification if something is off etc..) I used it on a big ecommerce project once and it was incredibly useful for making sure everything worked reliably as I could see the inner workings at all times in staging. V.handy.

Answer (score 14):

#### It's quite simple: the subject/observer pattern is not useful for an event system.

The observer pattern doesn't lend itself to saying, "This thing was updated by X".  Instead it simply says that it was updated. I have actually created [a flexible mediator class](https://github.com/morrisonlevi/Ardent/blob/f70a061a5f5d1999c13af8cdbc057c41c84cd1f3/src/HashingMediator.php) that could be leveraged for an event system.  Depending on your needs, a more rigid API might be helpful, but you can use that as inspiration.

#### So when is the subject/observer pattern useful?

It's a fairly common pattern when updating a GUI because some object changed. It doesn't really need to know what changed it or why, just that it needs to update.  The nature of HTTP doesn't really lend itself to this particular pattern because your PHP code isn't tied directly to the HTML.  You have to make a new request to update it.

In short, the Subject/Observer pattern isn't really that useful in PHP. Furthermore, the interface is not that useful because you have use `instanceof` to get the proper subject type.  I'd just write my own interface and not deal with it.

Comment: Guess who stumbled upon your answer again. Just read that code. Why not use `\SplObjectStorage` for that?

Comment: @kaiser Use `SplObjectStorage` for what, exactly? You mean the mediator class?

Comment: Yes, for the _mediator_ class.

Comment: `SplObjectStorage` only allows objects as keys – the mediator class is using string keys. I suppose you could switch but I don't really see the point.

Answer (score 7):

These two interfaces have no magic functionality attached to them, so implementing them does nothing.  They're really only used for reference purposes.  There are other PHP internal interfaces like this such as [`SeekableIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.seekableiterator.php).  There is no magic functionality attached to the `seek` method, and you have to implement it yourself.

There are some PHP internal interfaces and such as `Traversable` that get special functionality, but this is not the case for `SplSubject` and `SplObserver` -- it's essentially just a suggested interface for an implementation of the Observer pattern.

As for *what* happened, that information is not part of the interface since it's not abstract.  It's up to you to implement.

```
interface Event extends SplSubject {
   public function getEventData();
}

class MyEvent implements Event {
   //MySubject implementation above
   public function getEventData() {
      return "this kind of event happened";
   }
}
```

You could also ignore the `Event` interface entirely or just use `instanceof` checks (ugly) to see what kind of "Subject" is being passed to the method.

As for a real world example, [this link](http://devzone.zend.com/1732/implementing-the-observer-pattern-with-splobserver-and-splsubject/) provides one, although the use of `SplObserver`/`SplSubject` are not strictly necessary; they are just interfaces after all.  Essentially, you could have `ExceptionHandler` subject class and some observers, for example, `Mailer`.  You can use `set_exception_handler(array($handler, 'notify'));` and any exception that is thrown notifies all observers (e.g. `Mailer`, which sends an email about the exception that was caught -- you would have to get the exception from some other method/member of `ExceptionHandler`).

**EDIT:** I see from the comments that you plan to use another argument to to `update` to pass the event as a separate object.  I guess that's all right, but my suggestion is just to not separate the Subject and Event concepts and give the Subject the ability to either contain event data or be the event data itself.  You would have to check that the event object you receive is not null.

Answer (score 1):

As any interface it is useless until you implement it. By implementing those you can have event driven application

Imagine you have an event "applicationStart" you need to run 10 functions on it.

```
function applicationStart() {
   // Some other logic 
   fnCall1();
   fnCall2();
   fnCall3();
   fnCall4();
   fnCall5();
   fnCall6();
   fnCall7();
   fnCall8();
   fnCall9();
   fnCall10();
   // Some other logic 
}
```

Now imagine you need to test this function you would trigger dependency on all other 10 functions.

If you use SplSubject/SplObserver:

```
function applicationStart() {
    // Logic
    $Subject->notify();
    // Logic
}
```

Now when you test it you just need to make sure that you trigger event. Without execution of other functions.

Plus code looks cleaner as you do not polute it with business logic that does not belong there. And one nice easy place to add triggers

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/thephpleague/event it does the job very well. I think it's the best package today for this purposes. I also doesn't see any value in

```
public function notify(/* without args */) {
```

With league/event you will have following. For example I have email list and want to handle events when new email is added to the list.

```
class EmailList
{
    const EVENT_ADD_SUBSCRIBER = 'email_list.add_subscriber';
    public function __construct($name, $subscribers = [])
    {
        // do your stuff 
        $this->emitter = new Emitter(); 
    }


    /**
     * Adds event listeners to this list
     * @param $event
     * @param $listener
     */
     public function addListener($event, $listener)
     {
         $this->emitter->addListener($event, $listener);
     } 

    /**
     * Adds subscriber to the list
     * @param Subscriber $subscriber
     */
    public function addSubscriber(Subscriber $subscriber)
    {
        // do your stuff 
        $this->emitter->emit(static::EVENT_ADD_SUBSCRIBER, $subscriber);
    }
}

// then in your code
$emailList = new EmailList();
$emailList->addListener(EmailList::EVENT_ADD_SUBSCRIBER, function($eventName, $subscriber) {
});
```