# What conceptual difference between traits and multiple inheritance?

Tags: language-agnostic, multiple-inheritance, traits

From what I've read and what I've seen, I consider multiple inheritance as a bad practice, not by itself but because it leads beginner to use everywhere where more elegant design patterns might be useful and more meaningful.

Some languages have chosen not to implement multiple inheritance and then have chosen to implement traits (e.g. PHP). The only interesting and substantial difference I see between multiple inheritance and traits I see is a linguistic one: while "inheritance" indicates some kind of shared nature, "trait" stands more for features.

Is there any other important difference I'm missing that would explain why some consider that multiple inheritance was inappropriate and that, now, traits are appropriate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Traits vs. Interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205083/php-traits-vs-interfaces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use traits to fake multiple inheritance, but I believe the basic difference is a conceptual one. A parent-child relation is a  "is-a" relation.

If you have a Furniture class, with a Table child and a PicknickTable child, you have Picknicktable is-a Table is-a Furniture (hmm, is furniture countable like that? nvrmnd).

With traits, you just say: I hate to keep on writing the code to put stuff on a surface, so I write the "putStuffOnThisThing" trait, and they have it. This is not inheritance! The basic fault behind such reasoning might be is that you want to look at traits as a different way to show hierarchies while you shouldn't. It is no substitution for an actual good design, it is a trick in the toolbox that you could misuse for multiple inheritance, but you might be better use as a way to avoid writing some lines several times.

So in defence of the comparison: traits have some of the same problems as multiple inheritance, like the problem you need to address with aliasing in case of multiple things with the same name. While this is not exactly the diamond problem, it comes awfully close.