# what is traits and use of traits in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, traits

I searched a lot on internet but I didn't find a proper answer.
Sound like traits and inheritance have same work. how traits are different from inheritance and use of traits.

Comment: The [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) has a whole page about traits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205083/traits-vs-interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated with multiple inheritance and Mixins.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php